# List C++ Поиск максимального элемента в list

Tags: c++, stl, списки, std-list

**Нужно найти максимальный элемент**. Я не знаю как это сделать. Пробовал через итераторы`(.begin(), .end())` c добавлением счетчика, ничего не получается.

Как это сделать?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>     
#include <iterator> 
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
   list<int> myList; 
   for(int i = 0; i < 15; i++)
   {
       myList.push_back(rand()%20); 
   }

   cout << "Список: ";
   for ( list<int>::iterator it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); it++)
   {
    cout << *it << " ";
   }

auto max=myList.front();//a[0];// ето числовое значение а не индекс;
   for (auto l=0;l<myList.size(); l+=1) //l++
   {
     auto hlp=max+l;
     if(hlp>max) //if a[i]>max(a[0])
     {
       max=hlp;
       cout<<"max: "<<max<<endl;
     }
     //a[i]>max;
   }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проще всего -

```
cout << "max: " << *max_element(myList.begin(),myList.end()) << endl;
```

Если очень нужно самому написать -

```
int max=myList.front();
for(auto l: myList)
    if (max < l) max = l;
cout << "max: " << max << endl;
```

Если и это не нравится -

```
int max=myList.front();
for(auto it = myList.begin(); it != myList.end(); ++it)
    if (max < *it) max = *it;
cout << "max: " << max << endl;
```